# syntax error, unexpected token "endforeach", expecting "elseif" or "else" or "endif"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

So I made a jetstream project, this is my first time using jetstream. My problem is that for some reason the index page of the program says that I didn't close the foreach loop, when actually I have. I am pretty sure it was working until I added a way to store a data in the column and it didn't work after that. Is there a problem with the storing feature or is there a problem with the @?

program/index.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Program') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <a href="{{ route('program.create' )}}" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green--700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Tambah Program</a>
          <br/>

          @foreach ($program as $programs)
            <a href="{{ route('program.show', $program->id) }}" class="group block max-w-xs mx-auto rounded-lg p-6 bg-white ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 shadow-lg space-y-3 hover:bg-sky-500 hover:ring-sky-500">
              <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 stroke-sky-500 group-hover:stroke-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><!-- ... --></svg>
                <h3 class="text-slate-900 group-hover:text-white text-sm font-semibold">{{ $program->year }}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
          <br/>
          @empty
            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <td colspan="2" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                {{ __('No programs') }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach          
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

ProgramController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreProgramRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateProgramRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Models\Program;

class ProgramController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $program = Program::all();

        return view('program.index', compact('program'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('program.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreProgramRequest $request)
    {
        Program::create($request->validated());

        return redirect()->route('program.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Program $program)
    {
        return view('program.show', compact('program'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Program $program)
    {
        return view('program.edit', compact('program'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateProgramRequest $request, Program $program)
    {
        $program->update($request->validated());

        return redirect()->route('program.index');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Program $program)
    {
        $program->delete();

        return redirect()->route('program.index');
    }
}
```

StoreProgramRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class StoreProgramRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'tahun' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`@empty`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#if-statements) directive needs to be closed as like other blade directives.

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Program') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <a href="{{ route('program.create' )}}" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green--700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Tambah Program</a>
          <br/>

          @foreach ($program as $programs)
            <a href="{{ route('program.show', $program->id) }}" class="group block max-w-xs mx-auto rounded-lg p-6 bg-white ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 shadow-lg space-y-3 hover:bg-sky-500 hover:ring-sky-500">
              <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 stroke-sky-500 group-hover:stroke-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><!-- ... --></svg>
                <h3 class="text-slate-900 group-hover:text-white text-sm font-semibold">{{ $program->year }}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
          <br/>
          @endforeach

          @empty($program)
            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <td colspan="2" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                {{ __('No programs') }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endempty
          
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Alternatively, use [`forelse`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops):

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Program') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <a href="{{ route('program.create' )}}" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green--700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Tambah Program</a>
          <br/>

          @forelse ($program as $programs)
            <a href="{{ route('program.show', $program->id) }}" class="group block max-w-xs mx-auto rounded-lg p-6 bg-white ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 shadow-lg space-y-3 hover:bg-sky-500 hover:ring-sky-500">
              <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 stroke-sky-500 group-hover:stroke-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><!-- ... --></svg>
                <h3 class="text-slate-900 group-hover:text-white text-sm font-semibold">{{ $program->year }}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
          <br/>
          @empty
            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <td colspan="2" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                {{ __('No programs') }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endforelse
          
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Comment: I got an error with the endif an unexpected token "endif". The seems to point to another file in the storage/framework/views, I didn't even do anything there.

Comment: @GizmoHey can you provide the full error message? You might want to edit your original question to add it there if it’s quite long.

Comment: Actually I figured it out, I tried to changed the for each a bunch of times and it keeps giving me a property id error. The reason it happened is because I named the program as programs in the foreach parameter. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to change `@foreach` to `@forelse`

```php
@forelse ($users as $user)
    <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
    <p>No users</p>
@endforelse
```

after editing will be like this

```php
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Program') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <a href="{{ route('program.create' )}}" class="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green--700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Tambah Program</a>
          <br/>

          @forelse ($program as $programs)
            <a href="{{ route('program.show', $program->id) }}" class="group block max-w-xs mx-auto rounded-lg p-6 bg-white ring-1 ring-slate-900/5 shadow-lg space-y-3 hover:bg-sky-500 hover:ring-sky-500">
              <div class="flex items-center space-x-3">
                <svg class="h-6 w-6 stroke-sky-500 group-hover:stroke-white" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><!-- ... --></svg>
                <h3 class="text-slate-900 group-hover:text-white text-sm font-semibold">{{ $program->year }}</h3>
              </div>
            </a>
          <br/>
          @empty
            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
              <td colspan="2" class="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white whitespace-nowrap">
                {{ __('No programs') }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          @endforelse          
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

for more info check the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops)

Comment: I tried it and it gave me a property id error "Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance." Does this mean there's a problem with the database connection?

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it helped me. For what cause the property id error, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach ($test as $data)
// do whatever you want 
@if($data=="test")
   $val=1;
@else
  $val=0;
@endif

@endforeach

// If you are opening a directive its must be closed.
```

Comment: works to me @ms

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this logic

```
@forelse ($users as $user)
  <li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
@empty
  <p>No users</p>
@endforelse enter code here
```

You can check the doc for more details https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Comment: I tried and got a Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. Why is that?

Comment: you are messing up program and programs. check your implementation carefully. for some reason, you decided to put programs for the single element and program for the collection. so inside your loop it should be programs->id and not program->id.

Comment: I really advise here to follow the primary naming convention which is programs for the returned collection and program for each individual element.

Comment: You're right about me messing up the program, it turns out I originally named it as program in the controller so I guess it couldn't find the id of programs since it never exist. Thank you so much for your answer, you taught me a lot.